# Texture and normal map on the same object in blender native renderer

Tags: blender

I'm learning blender and I saw you can have both mapped texture and normal map on the same object via mixer node in Cycles renderer. Can I do the same in Blender Renderer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can add [several procedural or image textures](https://www.blender.org/manual/render/blender_render/textures/introduction.html) if you wish (there is a limit of 18 textures to a Blender Render material).

In the texture properties there is a list of available texture slots, just [add a new one to an unused slot](https://www.blender.org/manual/render/blender_render/textures/assigning_a_texture.html) and adjust it's properties.

[image: texture properties]

Comment: Oh, this makes sense now. Thank you!